# What is the expectation of the number of times you need to roll

Tags: matlab

I'm interested to write something using Matlab to simulate the number of times you need to roll a dice. (Maybe the re-roll is only done once?)

I'll need to keep re-rolling the die, until a unique number appears.
Below is the code I have up to now.

Any help is appreciated.

```
% N: the max number a roll of the fair die can take    
N = 6; 

% M: number of trials. Each trial is a sequence of rolls, and it
% terminates once you see K N's in a row.
M = 1; 
K = 1;

% initialize the trials vector. The m-th entry is going to store
% the number of rolls performed in the m-th trial.
trials = zeros(M,1);

% t0: record the start time of the simulation
t0 = clock();

% This for loop is to run the M trials.
for m = 1:M

    % collection: sequence of rolls. It's initialized with K
    % samples drawn from a uniformly distributed integer random
    % variable, because the minimal length of collection has to 
    % be K.

    % Here begins the loop to roll the die until all 6 numbers appear
    % If any number is repeated, re-roll until a unique number appears & move on to the next number
    collection = randi(N,K,1);  
    collection(:,2) = randi(N,K,1); 
    if collection(:,2)~=collection(:,1) 
        collection(:,3) = randi(N,K,1)  
    else collection(:,2) = randi(N,K,1)
    end

    if collection(:,3)~=(collection(:,1) && collection(:,2))
        collection(:,4) = randi(N,K,1)  
    else collection(:,3) = randi(N,K,1)
    end

    if collection(:,4)~=(collection(:,1)&& collection(:,2) && collection(:,3))
        collection(:,5) = randi(N,K,1)  
    else collection(:,4) = randi(N,K,1)
    end

    if collection(:,5)~=(collection(:,1)&& collection(:,2) && collection(:,3) && collection(:,4))
        collection(:,6) = randi(N,K,1)  
    else collection(:,5) = randi(N,K,1)
    end

    if collection(:,6)=(collection(:,1)&& collection(:,2) && collection(:,3) && collection(:,4) && collection(:,5))
        collection(:,6) = randi(N,K,1)  
    end

    % now that the last K rolls are all N's, we take note of the number 
    % of rolls performed in this trial
    trials(m) = length(collection);
end

% we measure how much time the simulation has spent by
% computing the time difference between now and t0
elapsed_time = etime(clock(), t0)

% the Monte Carlo estimate, which should be close to your analytical 
% solution.
mean(trials)
```

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: You sure it has to be `collection(:,6)=(collection(:,1)...)`? A `=` is an assignment, i.e. `collection(:,6)` will be set to the value on the right side. A comparison would be `==`

Comment: You sure it has to be `collection(:,3)~=(collection(:,1) && collection(:,2))`? if You want to check whether column 3 is different from column 1 and also different from column  2, it should be written as `(collection(:,3)~=collection(:,1)) & (collection(:,3)~=collection(:,2))`

Comment: Code is supposed to simulate rolling a die, keep rolling until u see all the numbers 1-6 at least once. Then count the number of rolls taken, repeat this by M (no of trials). Lastly take the average number of rolls needed, based on M trials.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it

```
function trials = diceExperiment( M )
trials = zeros(1,M);
for i = 1:M
    missingNum = true(1,6); % None of the six numbers are seen yet
    while (any(missingNum))
        currentNum = randi(6,1);
        trials(i) = trials(i)+1;
        missingNum(currentNum) = false;
    end
end
end % End of function
```

This would run this experiment for M times and the output trial would tell me how many rolls of the dice did it take each time to get all six numbers. You can add your clock stuff around this to measure time.